# DAG successfully completed even though its one of the task is getting failed internally with script

Tags: airflow, airflow-2.x, airflow-api

I am getting below DAG as "successfully completed instead of failed DAG, because one of the tasks failed with the SFTP connection. Can you please help me with how this update DAG with failed task. The script got executed, but it had internal error with execution of script

**

```
*** Reading local file: /home/airflow/airflow/logs/docker_PROJECT_stage/ssh_operator_remote5/2023-03-08T11:37:22.401933+00:00/1.log
[2023-03-08, 17:07:29 ] {taskinstance.py:1043} INFO - Dependencies all met for <TaskInstance: docker_PROJECT_stage.ssh_operator_remote5 manual__2023-03-08T11:37:22.401933+00:00 [queued]>
[2023-03-08, 17:07:29 ] {taskinstance.py:1043} INFO - Dependencies all met for <TaskInstance: docker_PROJECT_stage.ssh_operator_remote5 manual__2023-03-08T11:37:22.401933+00:00 [queued]>
[2023-03-08, 17:07:29 ] {taskinstance.py:1249} INFO - 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[2023-03-08, 17:07:29 ] {taskinstance.py:1250} INFO - Starting attempt 1 of 2
[2023-03-08, 17:07:29 ] {taskinstance.py:1251} INFO - 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[2023-03-08, 17:07:29 ] {taskinstance.py:1270} INFO - Executing <Task(SSHOperator): ssh_operator_remote5> on 2023-03-08 11:37:22.401933+00:00
[2023-03-08, 17:07:29 ] {standard_task_runner.py:52} INFO - Started process 18294 to run task
[2023-03-08, 17:07:29 ] {standard_task_runner.py:79} INFO - Running: ['airflow', 'tasks', 'run', 'docker_PROJECT_stage', 'ssh_operator_remote5', 'manual__2023-03-08T11:37:22.401933+00:00', '--job-id', '411', '--raw', '--subdir', 'DAGS_FOLDER/ssh_PROJECT.py', '--cfg-path', '/tmp/tmpzcxje_zg', '--error-file', '/tmp/tmpsvk7eiuu']
[2023-03-08, 17:07:29 ] {standard_task_runner.py:80} INFO - Job 411: Subtask ssh_operator_remote5
[2023-03-08, 17:07:29 ] {logging_mixin.py:109} INFO - Running <TaskInstance: docker_PROJECT_stage.ssh_operator_remote5 manual__2023-03-08T11:37:22.401933+00:00 [running]> on host aj-aws-austin-jackson-server
[2023-03-08, 17:07:29 ] {taskinstance.py:1448} INFO - Exporting the following env vars:
AIRFLOW_CTX_DAG_EMAIL=austin.jackson.jb@gmail.com
AIRFLOW_CTX_DAG_OWNER=airflow
AIRFLOW_CTX_DAG_ID=docker_PROJECT_stage
AIRFLOW_CTX_TASK_ID=ssh_operator_remote5
AIRFLOW_CTX_EXECUTION_DATE=2023-03-08T11:37:22.401933+00:00
AIRFLOW_CTX_DAG_RUN_ID=manual__2023-03-08T11:37:22.401933+00:00
[2023-03-08, 17:07:29 ] {ssh.py:136} INFO - Creating ssh_client
[2023-03-08, 17:07:29 ] {ssh.py:114} INFO - ssh_hook is not provided or invalid. Trying ssh_conn_id to create SSHHook.
[2023-03-08, 17:07:29 ] {base.py:79} INFO - Using connection to: id: arflw_ssh_remote_ec2. Host: 10.23.16.89, Port: None, Schema: , Login: root, Password: None, extra: {}
[2023-03-08, 17:07:29 ] {ssh.py:271} WARNING - Remote Identification Change is not verified. This won't protect against Man-In-The-Middle attacks
[2023-03-08, 17:07:29 ] {ssh.py:277} WARNING - No Host Key Verification. This won't protect against Man-In-The-Middle attacks
[2023-03-08, 17:07:29 ] {transport.py:1871} INFO - Connected (version 2.0, client OpenSSH_7.4)
[2023-03-08, 17:07:29 ] {transport.py:1871} INFO - Authentication (publickey) successful!
[2023-03-08, 17:07:29 ] {ssh.py:441} INFO - Running command: docker logs --follow shopping-PROJECT-scheduler-stage
[2023-03-08, 17:07:45 ] {ssh.py:473} INFO - ********************** Error in spftp connection ************************
**Some FTP Error occured : 
[2023-03-08, 17:07:45 ] {ssh.py:473} INFO - Error: connect: getConnection: All configured authentication methods failed
    at SftpClient.fmtError (/opt/PROJECT/node_modules/ssh2-sftp-client/src/index.js:111:22)
    at SftpClient.connect (/opt/PROJECT/node_modules/ssh2-sftp-client/src/index.js:249:37)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5) {
  code: 'ERR_GENERIC_CLIENT',
  custom: true
}**
[2023-03-08, 17:07:45 ] {taskinstance.py:1288} INFO - Marking task as SUCCESS. dag_id=docker_PROJECT_stage, task_id=ssh_operator_remote5, execution_date=20230308T113722, start_date=20230308T113729, end_date=20230308T113745
**[2023-03-08, 17:07:45 ] {local_task_job.py:154} INFO - Task exited with return code 0**
[2023-03-08, 17:07:45 ] {local_task_job.py:264} INFO - 0 downstream tasks scheduled from follow-on schedule check
```

Comment: Anyone can answer the above question

Answer (score 0):

Its hard to give a proper answer without seeing your code, however it appears you need to use some proper error handling with Airflow. We can mark a custom task / script as failed in the following way:

> ```
>  def check_list_contents():
>     if len(create_list()) == 0:
>         raise ValueError('List is empty, nothing to do')
>         return False
>     else:
>         print("There's stuff to do, Passed!")
>         return True
>
> check_list = ShortCircuitOperator(
>     task_id="check_list_empty",
>     provide_context=True,
>     python_callable=check_list_contents,
>     execution_timeout=timedelta(seconds=60)
>     )
> ```

This will check if a list called by the function is empty, and if it is will fail. It may be you need to check a similar condition with your script.